# Cannot install matplotlib basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, pip, matplotlib-basemap

I tried to install basemap on google colab and run these commands:

```
!apt-get install libgeos-3.5.0

!apt-get install libgeos-dev

!pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgeos-3.5.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libgeos-3.5.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgeos-3.5.0'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgeos-dev is already the newest version (3.6.2-1build2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
Collecting https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
  Using cached https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip.
```

I then cannot import basemap:

```py
>>> from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of errors here.

1. `apt` cannot find `libgeos`

   > `E: Unable to locate package libgeos-3.5.0`

   You may need to find another version of `libgeos` though I'm not sure what version. Perhaps this should match the installed dev version, `3.6.2`?
2. `pip` cannot install using the archive that you are providing.

   > `ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/archive/master.zip.`

   You can fix this by telling `pip` specifically what subdirectory it will find the package in:

   ```sh
   pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap#subdirectory=packages/basemap
   ```

   This will allow `pip` to find the correct package directory.

Comment: i am using python 3.8

Comment: Also i tried !pip install git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap and its says: ERROR: File "setup.py" not found for legacy project git+https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap.

Comment: It doesn't matter what python version you are using. In part `1` of my answer I am specifically talking about `libgeos` not python. Part `2` of my answer deals with the `basemap` package being in a different location, see the `#subdirectory=packages/basemap` at the end of the GitHub url, which tells `pip` where to find the package.

Comment: Fantastic! what was the version of `libgeos` that you used? You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70578876/edit) this answer if you want to add more detail about the steps you took

Comment: I used the version you said: 3.6.2 and i do exactly what you said

Answer (score 4):

Starting with `basemap` version 1.3.0, you can also install `basemap` directly using the precompiled binary wheels available in PyPI:

```
!pip install basemap
```

In case you need the high-resolution datasets, you have to install them explicitly:

```
!pip install basemap-data-hires
```